# Need a MongoDB query explanation

Tags: regex, mongodb

this is my first question on stackoverflow so be tolerant with a french rookie ;)
I have to simplify a MongoDB query and I've discovered this tool this morning on *docs.mongodb.org* and I really need to understand the methodology to continue to learn by myself.

Here is the query :

{$and: [{x: 2}, {y: 3}, {$and: [{z: 4}]}, {$or: [{name:{$regex: "toto.*"}}, {name:{$regex: "toto.*"}}]}]}

Thanks

Comment: Basically in SQL it is `x = 3 AND y = 3 AND z = 4 AND (name LIKE 'toto%' OR name LIKE 'toto%')`

Comment: @Sammaye: `AND z = 4`, from `{$and: [{z: 4}]}`

Comment: @Robin lol caught me in between edits :P

Answer (score 1):

Basically in SQL it is:

```
x = 3 AND y = 3 AND z = 4 AND (name LIKE 'toto%' OR name LIKE 'toto%')
```

This query can be massively simplified and I am not sure what tool you used to get this query, however, it can be brought down to:

```
{x: 2, y: 3, z: 4, name: {$in: [/^toto.*/, /^toto.*/]}}
```

This is since the default operator between query parts is actually `$and` so you only need `$and` in very specific cases, i.e. when you need to separately `$and` two clauses in a field or need to `$and` two separate `$or`s that, logically cannot be put together (for some reason).

I should note that in some drivers you need to replace the `$in` with an `$or` it depends on the constructs within the driver however, BSON regex objects (not the `$regex` operator) should be able to function within `$in` clauses etc.

Comment: If you simplify things, is there really a point in keeping `[/^toto.*/, /^toto.*/]` instead of `/^toto.*/`?

Comment: @Robin indeed I kept it cos I thought the second toto might have been a typo and actually there is something else there

Comment: Thank you :) With your help and docs.mongodb.org I can now understand the basics of queries. But I still don't understand why we have to keep the both "toto."

Comment: @Ben if that wasn't a typo you can remove the other